# Fix jQuery code problem or convert jQuery to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop-1.7

I am working with prestashop 1.7.I wrote jQuery code that affect on the category page. And I put it in the file path below:

```
public_html/themes/panda/assets/js/theme.js
```

But it will work only after refresh page. Is the code wrong? Is the file path wrong? Or should I introduce this jQuery code? Should I convert jQuery to Javascript? If so, how? Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hover_fly .hover_fly_btn").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).parents('.pro_first_box').find('#overlayToOpen').css('display', 'block');
  });

  $(".hover_fly .hover_fly_btn").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).parents('.pro_first_box').find('#overlayToOpen').css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pro_first_box">
  <div id="overlayToOpen">every things</div>
  <a href="" class=" product_img_link "><img src=" "></a>
  <div class="hover_fly ">
    <a class="hover_fly_btn " href="# ">
      <div class="hover_fly_btn_inner "><span>More info</span></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure your code is being executed? are you sure when your code is executed the html you are looking for exists?

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have shown which would cause it to only work after refreshing. Normally that's a sign of a caching issue, but it only happens once not repeatedly. In either case, check the console for errors when the code doesn't work. Also, this isn't a JS issue, so changing libraries or file paths wouldn't make a difference

Comment: am i beating a dead horse if i say jquery *is* javascript?

Comment: https://github.com/you-dont-need-x/you-dont-need-jquery

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the target element of your script exists in your page. In your case it is the element that has a class "hover_fly hover_fly_btn". If you are sure that the target element exists, add console.log() to your function to help you debug the problem and to make sure that the code was executed.